# Tab error even though my code looks formatted decently

Tags: python

[https://replit.com/@DevinMyers1/create-task-backup#main.py][1]

this is the code that has a tab error on line 48, I need help in order to continue my code I have tried spacing out the line itself but have struggled so I believe It may have been previous code I wrote holding me back.

Comment: There's definitely something wrong with your line 47. I'd say it's far from "looking formatted decently". :-)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] and add the code _as text_ in the question.

Comment: oh ok my bad kind of new to this is there any way I could fix it bc I'm pretty new with this

Comment: alalways put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer, and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: Just copy and paste the code into your question, then select it all and press ctrl-k on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

It's bad formatted from line 45 to 48.

[image]

This fix it.

```py
while True:
    if call2 == 'missedcall':
        print ('you missed an important call and lost your life  to a hitman')
        sys.exit

    if call2 == 'phonecall':
        n==input('wanna pick up(y/n)')
    break
```

This code is also wrong, you're using `while` in a very bad way.

Basically, if you've to do `while True`, it's because you want to some code run until a valid input is passed, and your code doesn't do that.

An example of how to structure your code better is this way

```py
if call2 == 'missedcall':
    print ('you missed an important call and lost your life  to a hitman')
    sys.exit

if call2 == 'phonecall':
    # This basically makes the user choose until he types n or y.
    while True:
        n==input('wanna pick up(y/n)')
        if n in ("y" or "n")
            break
        else:
            print("Please select a valid option")
```